# Diseño con HTML5 y CSS3

Tags: html, css

Intento realizar que el *sidebar* aparezca a la altura de *artículo 1* y se desplace con el *scroll* hasta el *artículo 2*

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo con *CSS* para que realice esa función?

Lo intenté con el siguiente código, pero sigue apareciendo igual y no de desplaza con el *scroll* el *sidebar*

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: red;
}

.banner{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;    
}
.post1, post2{
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}

aside{
    width: 19%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: silver;
    float: right;
}

.pagina{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    clear: both;

}

footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<header><h3>HEADER</h3></header>

<div class="banner"><h3>BANNER</h3></div>

<div class="contenido">

    <article class="post1"><h3>ARTICULO 1</h3></article>
    <article class="post2"><h3>ARTICULO 2</h3></article>

    <aside><h3>SIDEBAR</h3></aside>

</div>

<div class="pagina"><h3>PIE DE PAGINA 1</h3></div>

<footer><h3>FOOTER</h3></footer>
```

Comment: No entendí lo que intentas realizar, si pusieras una captura del diseño se entendería un poco, por certo, la propiedad "float" de css ya casi está en desuso, te recomiendo posicionar los elementos con la propiedad css flexbox "flex"

Comment: https://ibb.co/PNfzNYW aqui esta la imagen, lo que quiero es que el sidebar se encuentre en la pocision de donde dice articulo 1 y se vaya desplazando el sidebar conforme el scroll hasta llegar al final del elemento del articulo 2 y aun no me sale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que quieres algo como esto...
Usa flex, deja de lado float, y usa la propiedad sticky de css para el efecto del scroll.

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {padding-top: 75px;}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
}
.banner{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}

.contenido {
   display: flex;
   position: relative;
}
.articles {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.post1, .post2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

aside{
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: silver;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    margin: 10px 0;
    top: 85px;
}

.pagina{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    clear: both;
}

footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<header><h3>HEADER</h3></header>
<div class="banner"><h3>BANNER</h3></div>

<div class="contenido">
  <div class="articles">
      <article class="post1"><h3>ARTICULO 1</h3></article>
      <article class="post2"><h3>ARTICULO 2</h3></article>
  </div>
  <aside><h3>SIDEBAR</h3></aside>

</div>

<div class="pagina"><h3>PIE DE PAGINA 1</h3></div>

<footer><h3>FOOTER</h3></footer>
```